# Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Could not find a storyboard named 'visit_info' in bundle NSBundle

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, storyboard, visual-studio-2019

I am getting this error whenever I try to access a ViewController from another storyboard programmatically. It seems that my xamarin.ios app is not recognizing the storyboard which is holding the ViewController. My storyboard name is `visit_info.storyboard`.

I have tried the following code

```
 UIStoryboard board = UIStoryboard.FromName("visit_info", null);
            UIViewController ctrl = (visitController)board.InstantiateViewController("visitController");
            ctrl.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve;
            this.PresentViewController(ctrl, true, null);
```

Here is the full error that I am getting on the first statement above:

```
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Could not find a storyboard named 'visit_info' in bundle NSBundle </Users/amer/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B343541-D0E1-410E-880C-18E9FE0289D8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A01C5D60-96A8-4BF8-993B-C0D90EE7EE5A/samra_op2.app> (loaded)
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2043a126 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177f78 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff247e48a6 -[UIStoryboard name] + 0
    3   samra_op2                           0x0000000100696699 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
    4   ???                                 0x00000001062ec539 0x0 + 4398695737
```

Comment: In project targets -> `Build Phases` -> `Copy Bundle Resources`, does `visit_into.storyboard` exists?

Comment: is this on visual studio? I can't find it

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I didn't notice this was Xamarin. The exception you have means there is no storyboard named "visit_info", so you really need to check whether if the file is getting copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a typo there, your storyboard name is `visit_into.storyboard` while in your code it is UIStoryboard.FromName("`visit_info`", null);.

Please be careful with **into** and **info**.

Your codes looks fine:).

**Update**:

Follow my steps and do it again:

1.I created a new iOS project and `right click the project` --> `add` --> `new item` --> `ViewController With Storyboard`

2.Go to the storyboard you just created and Go to tool box, select a new ViewContrllor and  add it to the storyboard.

3.Go to the `properties` panel of ViewContrllor in storyboard and set the `Class` and `Storyboard ID` there, also check the `Use Storyboard ID`.

4.Then in the other `ViewController`, call your code:

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

    UIStoryboard board = UIStoryboard.FromName("visit_info", null);
    UIViewController ctrl = (visit_info)board.InstantiateViewController("visit_info");// here use storyboard ID
    ctrl.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve;
    this.PresentViewController(ctrl, true, null);
}
```

Comment: that's not the case . I only wrote the name wrong on stack overflow not on code

Comment: I just test the code and it works well. Can you please delete the visit_info.storyboard and recreate a new one then try again?

Comment: I tried it didn't change anything  , still facing the same problem .

Comment: Will you get the same problem if you call UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);?

Comment: if I use ```UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);``` it gives me an error on the second line saying that there is no controller named visitController . ```Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x6000028939c0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'visitController'```

Comment: visitController does not exist in Main.Storyboard.  board.InstantiateViewController("storyboardID"), you should pass the storyboardID when call board.InstantiateViewController.

Comment: I always have the controller name the same as storyboardID

Comment: @TaherEl-hares Can you please follow my updated answer and try again?

Comment: The code in your answer is working but only if I made another storyboard with a different name . Please check my answer below. @Jack Hua - MSFT

Comment: In the designer.cs, there is a line [Register("Test")], did you change it to new name?

Comment: If my solution work for you, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Yes I changed the register name when I changed the other values

Comment: I just change the name in my project and it also work. Maybe there are some cache on you side:).

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer but I need an explanation . When I made the controller        the first time I edited the name and then changed all other names related to the controller including controller class name in controller.cs , controller.designer.cs and controller properties .  When I tried the old name of the controller it somehow worked.